# Change positive to negative number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm very new to Ruby. Apologies if this topic has already been covered (I see switching neg to pos but not the other way around).

I am entering this in Codewars but getting an error message:

```
def make_negative(num) 
  if num <= 0 return num 
  else return num(*-1)
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - not providing the error message. Also not reading about syntax of `if/else` in ruby. You're missing an `end` there.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: *I see switching neg to pos but not the other way around* -- I'm curious what solution you saw for switching negative to positive? I would expect a very simple solution here (`num.abs`); no conditional needed. The concept of taking an "absolute value" (`abs`) is fairly universal across programming languages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Answer (score 4):

An alternative with a single branch: abs plus unary minus

```
def make_negative(num) 
  -num.abs
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason for writing this in a confusing way with `.-@`? I think `-num.abs` also works?

Comment: I don't think it's confusing if you know the method but you're right, `-num.abs` should also work and it's neat

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `end` for the `if...else` block. Furthermore, `num(*-1)` is raising an error because `num` isn't a method accepting arguments but a variable, and `*-1` isn't a valid Ruby expression.

This should work:

```
def make_negative(num) 
  if num <= 0 
    return num 
  else 
    return num * -1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be fine:

```rb
def make_negative(num)
  return num <= 0 ? num : num * -1
end
```

You have brackets around the `(*-1)` but you should be using `num * -1`.

Comment: I agree that a ternary looks better here, but it is functionally equivalent to if/else and it's more useful to beginners if code in the answer is not 100% different :)

Comment: Yeah, thats my thinking too.